# Which of the following first order formulae is logically valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Which of the following first order formulae is logically valid? Here $α(x)$ is a first order formula with $x$ as a free variable, and $β$ is a first order formula with no free variable.
>
> 1. $[β → (\exists x, α(x))] → [\forall x, β → α(x)]$
> 2. $[\exists x, β → α(x)] → [β → (\forall x, α(x))]$
> 3. $[(\exists x, α(x)) → β] → [\forall x, α(x) → β]$
> 4. $[(\forall x, α(x)) → β] → [\forall x, α(x) → β]$

---

#### My attempt :

1. If any is true then all need not be true.
2. If any is true then all need not be true.
3. If any is true then all need not be true.
4. Seems true, since only $x$ is bounded variable in $\alpha$.Actually LHS is equivalent(bi-conditional) to RHS ; so, implecation is also true.

> Can you explain with the help of example(s) for each option, please?

Comment: In (4), suppose $\alpha(x)$ means "$x$ is odd" and $\beta$ means "$0=1$" ...

Comment: On the other hand, (3) is logically valid. Let $x$ be arbitrary and assume $\alpha(x)$. Then $\exists x\,\alpha(x)$, so by the premise we get $\beta$. Thus $\beta$ and since we assumed $\alpha(x)$ we have $\alpha(x)\to\beta$. SInce $x$ was arbitarary, $\forall x(\alpha(x)\to\beta)$.

Comment: (1) and (2) are not; consider $0=0$ as $\beta$ and $(x=0)$ as $\alpha(x)$.

Comment: Your "AFIAK" statement is very terse - can you expand on your thoughts? Also, what is the source of the question?

Comment: This is competitive exam GATE's question.

Comment: By $\forall x,\alpha(x)\rightarrow\beta$ do you mean $\forall x[\alpha(x)\rightarrow\beta]$?

Comment: @bof, Yes, since $\beta$ doesn't contain $x$.

Comment: You need brackets because $\forall x[\alpha(x)\rightarrow\beta]$ is not equivalent to $[\forall x\alpha(x)]\rightarrow\beta$, regardless of whether $\beta$ contains $x$.

Comment: @bof, can you give explanation/answer, please?